# Opening xlsx file created with SpreadSheetGear

Tags: excel, spreadsheetgear

I have created a simple Excel file using SpreadSheetGear. If I save it as an xls file

```
workbook.SaveAs("file.xls", SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.Excel8);
```

and attach it to an email, I can open it on my phone (tested both with iPhone and Android).

If I save it as an xlsx file

```
workbook.SaveAs("file.xlsx", SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
```

and attach it to an email, I CANNOT open it on my phone.

If I open the xlsx file attachment on my computer and save it with no changes and attach it to an email, I now can open it on my phone.

Apparently Excel saves the file differently than SSG. The file size of the xlsx file attachment is 9 KB. When I open it on my computer and save it, the new file size is 24 KB.

Some of my users prefer the xlsx format. Is there anything I can do with to make the SSG generated file attachment open like an Excel generated file attachement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS depends on certain attributes being present in the worksheet data of the Open XML file format to properly parse these files.  SpreadsheetGear does not write these attributes out because they are listed as optional in the Open XML file format specification and, also, omitting them reduces file size, as you have noted.  Excel, for whatever reason, always writes out these optional attributes and other third-party components often times rely on their presence to function correctly.  SpreadsheetGear V5 added a workaround to write out these attributes by enabling a certain "Experimental" option.  This option was added because the OLE DB provider also exhibits this errant behavior.  You might try something like the following and see if this helps in getting SpreadsheetGear to better work with your viewer:

```
IWorkbookSet workbookSet = Factory.GetWorkbookSet();
workbookSet.Experimental = "OleDbOpenXmlWorkaround";
IWorkbook workbook = workbookSet.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\temp\BadWorkbook.xlsx");
workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\GoodWorkbook.xlsx", FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
```

Please see the SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbookSet.[Experimental](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbookSet~Experimental.html) property for more information on this feature.

From what I can tell, iOS/Andriod/etc often also depend on other certain optional features available in the file formats that SpreadsheetGear either doesn't support or write out by default.  For instance, iOS depends on a "data cache" stored within charts to display chart series data points and SpreadsheetGear's support for writing out this data cache is limited.  This can result in charts not displaying as expected in iOS, Android, etc.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, good explanation. I would never have figured this one out.