# jxls ms office 2010 not working

Tags: excel, jxls

I'm using jxls-core 1.0.

I made xls file in ms office excel 2007 -> working
I revised xls file in ms office excel 2010 -> not working.

Why is it jxls only available in Excel 2007?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jxls 1.x supports all Excel versions supported by [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) which it uses under the hood.

It seems MS Office Excel 2010 file format is a little bit different. For example see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172136/cant-read-excel-2010-file-with-apache-poi-first-row-number-is-1) where a user has an issue reading xlsx file saved in Excel 2010.

Possibly the latest POI versions already support Excel 2010 format fully but I have not checked it. So you may try to set the latest version of POI as dependency for your project and try it.

If it still not working then the only option would be to save the file in the 2007 Excel format.