# Reading cell values from excel returns empty using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm facing something different problem while reading values from excel for the particular file, will receive this excel file from different user.
If I do copy paste the content of the file or save as the file means program reading cell values of excel. otherwise it gives empty result.

```
String Email,Name;
Cell EmailCell = CurrentRow.getCell(0);
Cell NameCell  = CurrentRow.getCell(1);
if(EmailCell != null && EmailCell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK && NameCell != null && NameCell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
EmailCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
NameCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
**Email = EmailCell.toString();
Name  = NameCell.toString();** -- getting empty value for email and name

Sample Excel format
**Email         Name**
test@mail.com   TEST ONE
test2@mail.com  TEST TWO
```

I cannot re modify the excel since i'm getting it from the different user. Code will automatically take the excel file and process.
Please help someone knows the solution.

Comment: Side note - Which version of Apache POI are you using? If you're using the latest version,  you shouldn't be using `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`. You should be using `CellType.BLANK`.

Comment: even if i have value in cell also im getting empty thats the problem here

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification on the issue. That being said, I still think you should make that change, as the `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK` (and similar `enum` values) are deprecated.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I suspect `CurrentRow` had not be got at all and this code part will not be processed therefore. Reason why a row could not be got see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172136/cant-read-excel-2010-file-with-apache-poi-first-row-number-is-1/27192300#27192300